# DialogPreference using Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I'm trying to make a DialogPreference that uses GoogleMaps, but I'm having difficulty getting this to work. Here's my code:

```
public class MapDialogPreference extends DialogPreference {
    private static final String TAG = "MapDialog";

    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

    public MapDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.map_dialog_preference);
    }

}
```

I'm trying this out on an Android 4.3 device, and I keep getting the following error:

```
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    at android.preference.DialogPreference.onCreateDialogView(DialogPreference.java:343)
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    at android.preference.DialogPreference.showDialog(DialogPreference.java:287)
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    at android.preference.DialogPreference.onClick(DialogPreference.java:266)
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    at android.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:950)
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    at android.preference.PreferenceScreen.onItemClick(PreferenceScreen.java:215)
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2788)
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3463)
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:585)
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4738)
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
02-17 07:59:29.977: E/AndroidRuntime(30042):    ... 22 more
```

For reference, the XML fragment is:

```
<fragment 
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work. Anyone have any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because I'm using PreferenceFragments, which doesn't exist in the support library. The work around for this I'm using is to use a different map for pre-Honeycomb devices, as follows:

```
public MapDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        usingGoogleMaps=true;
        setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.google_map_dialog_preference);
    } else {
        usingGoogleMaps=false;
        setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.map_dialog_preference);
    }
}
```

I could in theory get this to work using the support library if an older version, and the main library if the newer version, but I decided not to go that route.